# Looking for online OpenGL 3.1+ tutorials

Tags: opengl

Whenever I do a search for OpenGL tutorials I always land on the NeHe tutorials.
However those cover the immediate mode stuff and are outdated.

Does anyone knows of OpenGL tutorials covering the latest 3.1 enhancements?

Comment: What? Closed? (And the duplicate answeered with a nice reference to http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ downvoted?) Are you guys envious of (real) police officers here? ;)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, your only choices other than immediate mode are display lists and vertex arrays. [Lesson #12](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=12) covers Display Lists. [Lesson #45](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=45) cover Vertex Arrays and Vertex Buffer Objects.

It seems to me like most of the latest OpenGL changes involve GLSL and textures. I don't think you'll get much benefit out of exploring those topics until you master the basics (which I'm still doing). There's plenty of articles on display lists, vertex arrays and VBOs if you search for them.

Comment: Are there any tutorials that are cross-platform (instead of Windows-specific)?

Comment: @AndersonGreen http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ is